# Camel Blueprint XML DSL route Debugging

Tags: debugging, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I was searching on the web but not able to find any example how to debug camel routes which are defined using XML DSL (Blueprint).

Any example/pointers would be great.

Regards,
A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some details on the Camel website, about debugging routes.

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-debug-my-route.html

> **Sidenote:** I wrote a blog post about the Debugger SPI in Camel, for people
>   interested a bit in the history:
>   http://www.davsclaus.com/2010/10/paris-and-easier-camel-route-debugging.html

If you are looking for a visual tooling for debugging, then hawtio has this: http://hawt.io/, there is a video showing this a bit in action:

- http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/06/introducing-new-apache-camel-based-ipaas.html

The hawtio tooling allows you to connect to a JVM container running Camel applications, eg sine you mention Blueprint you may use Apache Karaf / ServiceMix. You can then either run hawtio on your computer and remote connect to the container and remote debug the Camel routes from a web console. Or you can install hawtio in Karaf / ServiceMix directly and also use a web console to debug the routes.

> **Sidenote:** Besides hawtio there is some Karaf shell commands which allows you to
>   trace Camel routes at runtime. Though there is no debugger (yet). But
>   there is JMX operations you can use to "debug" but its a bit
>   cumbersome. Though the JMX API is what the hawtio tooling is using,
>   meaning what hawtio can do, you can also do with JMX yourself, or
>   create your own tooling etc.